# how to interate through multiple values in locals in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to create an iam policy in terraform , such that I can write policy statement , such as below, but I would like to create a variable such as array and iterate through that to create policy for each resource via terraform.

```
   "Effect": "Allow", 
    "Action": "*"
    "Resources" :
```

```
locals{
  resources = ["lambda", "s3" , "ec2"]
}
```

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "allowpolicy" {
   name= "resourcesaccessallowed"
   
   #iterate through the resources list here in locals
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for_each` which will create `allowpolicy` for each of your `local.resources`:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "allowpolicy" {
   name= "resourcesaccessallowed"
   for_each = local.resources   
}
```